# 'No such file or directory' after downloading xampp from SourceForce following Ubuntuportal's tutorial

Tags: permissions, xampp

I am trying to install XAMPP in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. In this regard I am following this [tutorial](http://ubuntuportal.com/2013/12/how-to-install-xampp-1-8-3-for-linux-in-ubuntu-desktop.html). I executed successfully in terminal :

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run/download
```

Now I would like to execute

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer
```

But I am getting this error :

```
chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-5.6.8-0-installer.run’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The `chmod +x` command should also work without `sudo`, as the you just downloaded it to your home directory and therefore are the file owner, I assume. It's a good idea to only use `sudo` as often as necessary, but as rarely as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong XAMPP download link. Instead use :

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

And then :

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

When it is done just follow the rest of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer from hg8 does not work for you, here is an alternative:

Download the latest version from the [official download page](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Change directory to the folder containing the downloaded file and run the following commands:

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-*-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```